How are user logins from different devices managed in Asp.net core Identity? (Token-based authentication)
The user needs to login in multiple devices. Each login creates a session with its own token and refresh token. The tokens are stored in the database and then each token the api receives is validated against the db. When a user logs out the token will be deleted from the database so it is no longer valid.
I assume such scenario to be quite common, but it seems it is not built into the asp.net core identity, which means I need add my own table for the sessions. And since people say "making up your own identity framework is stupid", I'm wondering, am I approaching this wrong, or is it not built into the asp.net core identity (why?)?
Update
So after the talk with @Dai in the comments, the question seems to boil down to: How is instant logout achieved in token based apps? And isn't that built in?

"The tokens are stored in the database and then each token the api receives is validated against the db. "  - that sounds like OAuth2/OIDC - if that's the case, then the DB shouldn't be used to verify tokens (except for refresh_token), you only need to cryptographically verify the token and certain claims (most importantly the aud, exp, and scope claims). Also, the RP shouldn't be storing any tokens at all - so please explain how your system is set-up...

"When a user logs out the token will be deleted from the database so it is no longer valid." - stateless bearer tokens shouldn't be saved to a DB in the first place so there shouldn't be anything to delete thus making this point moot (hence why access-tokens should have short lifetimes, and it's why token-revocation is a pain, fortunately it should be unnecessary in most cases).

@Dai The reason for storing the token is instant logout. are you suggesting we just wait for the tokens to expire?

First-off, what do you mean by "logout"? That sounds like something for browser-based users, in which case you won't be using OAuth2 tokens at all, but ASP.NET's CookiesAuthentication, where "instant logout" is done by simply sending a Set-Cookie header to auto-expire the user's cookies - or by using session-expiration on a cookie (nothing to do with ASP.NET Session state btw).

The client is a desktop app. There'll be external login by Google too (Guess you mean a different thing by oauth2 though).  I issue my own tokens no matter how the user authenticates (creating account, or using google account). How is my logout different than a browser based app (except using tokens vs cookies)?

@Dai thanks, you lead me in the right direction.

It is not built into the Asp.net core Identity because tokens are mainly there  for stateless authentication (no db). And how stateless token-based logout is achieved is discussed here.
No db should be used for token based authentication.
